# How can I locate and view Javascript that's being used on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, firebug

How can I locate and view specific Javascript that's being used on webpage?

For example, let's say I'm looking over a page's source, and I find an element like this:

```
<img border="0" alt="" onmouseout="hidetrail();" 
onmouseover="showtrail('image1.jpg',225);" 
src="image2.jpg"></img>
```

...how could I then locate and view the specific Javascript/AJAX that provides/implements the functionality contained within that tag? In other words, where would I typically find "hidetrail()" and "showtrail()" defined?

Is there a process to finding this with a tool like Firebug?

Comment: Chrome devtools -> Sources?

Comment: do a search within the script tab in firebug - it should help

Comment: use firebug...its a firefox extention which is really handy

Comment: I've been using them, but I still can't find it -- there are numerous external Javascript files being loaded, as well. Is there some way to catch what's happening with a "breakpoint", so to speak?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on page view source,Then search for hidetrail ur function  using CTRL f it will be written inside javascript, Or the Javascript may be linked through external source then in that case you have to search in that externally added file.